# VB.NET - Module Interpreted as Class in VBE

Tags: vb.net, vba, dll

I am building a VB.NET class library that will be used for VBA Projects. In my library, I have a module called "Globals" I wish to store some global (Library level) properties and methods in:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComVisible(True)>
Public Module Globals
    <ComVisible(True)>
    Public Const TestGlobal As Integer = 0
End Module
```

However, when I reference my library in the Excel VBE, my module shows up as a Class and I can't see my constant variable in the Object Browser:

[image: VBE Object Browser]

What am I missing or doing incorrectly that's causing my module to show up as a class?

Comment: A `Module` is just a static class.  It gets exposed to COM as an interface, and the VBE OB displays it as a `Class` because it can be called through `IDispatch`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14549503/4088852) for a more in depth explanation. IIR the constant will be COM visible if you declare it as whatever the VB equivalent to `public static readonly int` is.

Comment: That makes sense now why it's showing up as a class. Do you have any idea what a VBA Module equivalent would be in VB.NET?

Comment: A VB.NET Module. A good illustration of that is that you can give a VBA Module properties.  A VBA Module is just the COM equivalent of a static class.

Comment: Gotcha. Does this mean there is nothing I can do in my code to make the VBE see my Globals module as a module and not a class? If there is a way to do this, what would I have to change in my code?

Comment: Does it really *matter* if it shows up as a `Class` or a `Module`? FWIW, VBA.Global shows up as a `Class` too.

Comment: True, but in the VBA Library there is other modules such as VBA.Constants and VBA.Strings and in the VBE, they are displayed as Modules, not Classes. Why can't I do the same? If I have to use only classes, that's fine; I'm just trying to find the best way modularize all my methods and constants.

Comment: The VBA standard library wasn't written in .NET, either ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's somewhat of an "impedance mismatch" between VB.NET and COM.  COM works primarily with interfaces, and .NET builds the .tlb files from VB projects in a way that makes them more accessible to COM.  A `Module` in VB.NET is basically just a static class in the managed world.  When the interop assembly is built from your code, it sees a class, wraps it in an interface, and attaches the interface to the class:

[image: OP's code in ITypeLib Viewer]

Note that you *can't* provide your own interface implementation for a `Module`, because static classes in .NET can't implement interfaces.

---

The other thing that you can't do in .NET is create member procedures that aren't wrapped in a class.  That is basically what a `Module` is in the COM world.  For example, take a look at the IDL for the VBA Strings module:

> ```
> module Strings {
>     [entry(516), helpcontext(0x000f665f)]
>     short _stdcall Asc([in] BSTR String);
>     [entry(537), helpcontext(0x000f6e9f)]
>     BSTR _stdcall _B_str_Chr([in] long CharCode);
>     [entry(608), helpcontext(0x000f64e2)]
>     VARIANT _stdcall _B_var_Chr([in] long CharCode);
>     [entry(517), helpcontext(0x000f6ea0)]
> ```

Note that all of the entries have a .dll entry point specified.  That's basically because you're making raw function calls of the variety you'd find in the C world.  If an analogue  existed in the .NET world, it would be a `Sub` or `Function` declared at the ***namespace*** level instead of the class (or module) level...

```
<ComVisible(True)>
Namespace SomeClass.Functions  

    <ComVisible(True)>
    Public Function Foo() As String
        Return "Foo"
    End Function    

End Namespace
```

...which obviously isn't valid .NET code.

---

On a related note, keep in mind that you aren't seeing the entire picture in VBA *either*.  VBA is basically built on top of COM, but it tries really hard to abstract away most of it.  A *VBA Module* can for all intents and purposes be treated as a static class.  For example, you can give them properties, public members, etc. At the end of the day, it really doesn't matter whether the VBA Object Browser sees something as a class, a module, or whatever - what matters is that you can use managed code from an unmanaged context. Just work around the differences in the 2 infrastructures to get something usable and call it a day:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComVisible(True)>
Public Enum Constants
    GlobalOne = 0
    GlobalTwo = 1
    GlobalEtc = 2
End Enum

<ComVisible(True)>
Public Class FunctionProvider
    <ComVisible(True)>
    Public Function Foo() As String
        'Note that the class doesn't need to keep track of "state" to be usable.
        Return "Foo"
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for this great documentation Comintern. I was never against only using classes (static or not) in my project. It was just confusing me why the VBE wasn't seeing my module for what it was but, it actually is interpreting it correctly as you pointed out. Since VB.NET static classes have no interface, is that related to the reason why, in the VBE, I don't get intellisense when I do my Library name followed by a period: `MyLibrary.`? In order for me to get intellisense, I find that I need to dimension an object of my library first. Or is that a completely different subject?

Comment: @SamSlaughterbeck - Yep. You need to declare it and create an instance first. A rough COM equivalent to a "default object" is an appobject, but there really isn't anything similar in .NET.  Just think of it like creating an `Application` object for your server.

Comment: Gotcha. No .NET equivalent... I figured as much.